# writing over 350 gb of data into json which is grouped by and used the collect list and partitioned with 2 columns

Tags: pyspark, pyspark-transformer

Is there any other solution for the below problem to write data faster: There is no constraint on the cluster size and configurations.

```
df = emp_df.join(mem_df on emp_df.col1 == mem_df.col2)

df.count() --> 217 millions

    grouped_df = df.groupBy(
        "col1",
        "col2",
        "col3",
        "col4",
        "col5"
    )

    df1 = grouped_df \
        .agg(f.collect_list(f.struct("col3", "col7", "col2", "col8", "col10")).alias("items")) \
        .orderBy("col1","col2","items.col8")
    
    df2 = df1.withColumn("newCol1", f.struct(*df1.columns)).drop(*df1.columns)
    df3 = df2.withColumn("newCol2", f.struct(*df2.columns)).drop(*df2.columns)
```

OUTPUT:

```
    {
        "newCol2": {
            "newCol1":  {
                "col1": "val1",
                "col2": "val2",
                "col3": "val3",
                "col4": "val4",
                "col5": "val5",
                "col6": "val6",
                "col7": "val7",         
                "col8": [{
                    "col4_1": "val8_1",
                    "col4_1": "val8_2",
                    "col4_1": "val8_3",
                    "col4_1": "val8_4",
                    "col4_1": "val8_5",
                    "col4_1": "val8_6"
                },
                {
                    "col4_1": "val8_11",
                    "col4_1": "val8_21",
                    "col4_1": "val8_31",
                    "col4_1": "val8_41",
                    "col4_1": "val8_51",
                    "col4_1": "val8_61"
                
                }...it can go upto 10 child
                
                ]
            }
        }
    }

df3.count() --> 90 millions
```

I am writing this into JSON as below:

```
df3.select("data", "newCol2.newCol1.col1", "newCol2.newCol1.col2") \
    .coalesce(1) \
    .write \
    .partitionBy("col1","col2") \
    .mode("overwrite") \
    .format("json") \
    .save("abc/json_data/")
```

**NOTE: The partition column "col1" is having around 35 Thousand distinct values.
The partition column "col2" can be present in multiple col1 partitions.
The total volumn of data is around 350 GB.**

***This is running for days and after 3 days and 8 hrs, I have cancelled it.***

PLATFORM: AZURE DATABRICKS.

Comment: Just curious: is there some reason why you need such giant JSON and not dump the data as parquet/parquet data set?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell the specific bottlenecks of your job without looking into the spark UI and your Databricks' environment details.

But, following are few suggestions from my end to reduce your job execution time:

- Try to balance the partitions according to your data using [`repartition`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.repartition.html) for the `emp_df` and `mem_df` before joining them to see if it improves the `join` performance. And, also consider [broadcasting](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.broadcast.html) the smaller dataframe but, it may not be of much help if both dataframes are large.
- If possible, reduce the number of columns and filter the dataframes before joining or grouping them. This will help in reducing the shuffling of your data.
- Remove any unnecessary actions from the code like `df.count()` when it is not necessary to reduce resource usage when not required.
- [Cache](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.cache.html) intermediate data when necessary to avoid recomputation.
- Avoid `orderBy` if it is not needed.

Try tinkering with spark properties and apply optimizations until your execution time gets down to a satisfactory value.

I'll also recommend you check out the official documentation targetted towards optimizations and performance tuning:

- [Spark Performance Tuning](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-performance-tuning.html)
- [Optimizing data workloads on Databricks](https://www.databricks.com/discover/pages/optimize-data-workloads-guide#intro)
- [Optimization recommendations on Azure Databricks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/optimizations/)